# Build XML using linq to objects

Tags: xml, linq-to-objects

I am trying to generate an XML file using the data from a class, which has a name and multiple addresses associated to the name. I am getting lost @ adding multiple addresses to the XElement. 
Can somebody please help me. 
Thanks in advance
BB.

My Classes :

```
     public class Subject
    {
        public ClueName name { get; set; }
        public List driverAddress { get; set;}
    }


 public class DriverAddress
    {
        public string house { get; set; }
        public string street1 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string zip4 { get; set; }
    } 

private string BuildRequestXML(List <Subject> input)
      {
           string subjectId = "S1" ;
           XElement req = new XElement("order",
                              new XElement("order_dataset",
                                  new XElement("subjects",
                                      from i in input
                                      select 
                                      new XElement("subject", new XAttribute("id", subjectId),
                                          new XElement("name",
                                                        new XElement("first",i.name.first),
                                                        new XElement("middle", i.name.middle ),
                                                        new XElement("last", i.name.last)
                                                       )
                                                    )
                                               ),
                                           new XElement("addresses",
                                                input.Select(c => {c.driverAddress.Select (d =>
                                                    new XElement("address",                                
                                                    new XElement("street1",d.street1),
                                                    new XElement("city",d.city),
                                                    new XElement("state",d.state),
                                                    new XElement("postalcode",d.postalcode)
                                                     )).ToList ();
                                                     }).ToList()
                                                        )
                                           )
                                     );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `input.Select(c => {c.driverAddress.Select (d =>` section.

You are already iterating though input as i, so can do along the lines of

```
from d in i.driverAddress
select new XElement("address", 
             new XElement("street1", d.Street1),
             new XElement("street2", d.Street2),
```

etc...

UPDATE: Since driver addresses should not be output as children of the subject, try the following:

```
var addresses = new List<DriverAddress>();
input.ForEach(delegate(Subject s) { s.driverAddress.ForEach(d => addresses.Add(d)); });


string subjectId = "S1";
XElement req = new XElement("order",
    new XElement("order_dataset",
        new XElement("subjects",
            from i in input
            select
            new XElement("subject", new XAttribute("id", subjectId),
                new XElement("name",
                    new XElement("first", i.name.first),
                    new XElement("middle", i.name.middle),
                    new XElement("last", i.name.last)
                )
            )
        ),
        new XElement("addresses",
                from d in addresses
                select new XElement("address",
                        new XElement("street1", d.street1),
                        new XElement("city", d.city),
                        new XElement("state", d.state),
                        new XElement("postalcode", d.postalcode)
                )
        )

    )
);
```

Comment: thank you. My requirement is that all the subjects should be under <subjects> tag and all the addresses under <addresses> tag. so, "input.Select(c => {c.driverAddress.Select (d =>" is not at all dependent on "i"

Comment: please could you post how you would like the resultant XML to look like?

Comment: <subjects>
  <subject subjectId="1">
    <firstName></firstName>
    <lastName></lastName>
  </subject>
  <subject subjectId="2">
    <firstName></firstName>
    <lastName></lastName>
  </subject>
   </subjects>
   <addresses>
       <address>
</address>
    <address>
        </address>
            <address>
                </address>
       </addresses>

Comment: edited, so that it builds addresses first into an IEnumberable<DriverAddress>